# How can I get the value of a JSON field in XSLT?

Tags: json, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I would like to fetch the below text via xslt. 
Input is -

```
{
   "Contact Id":"3333333333",
   "Contact No":"9811430620",
   "Email Id":"abhishek.jain@homecredit.co.in",
   "Last Name":"Jain","First Name":"Abhishek"
}
```

Now i need only this text in output : `3333333333`.

Pls do let me know how to do in xslt.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well the input is not XML but JSON it seems so you might need to use an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9.6 PE or EE and the `json-to-xml` functionality

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="json">
        <xsl:value-of select="json-to-xml(.)//*[@key = 'Contact Id']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That assumes that your input actually has the JSON inside of an XML input element `<json>{"Contact Id":"3333333333","Contact No":"9811430620","Email Id":"abhishek.jain@homecredit.co.in","Last Name":"Jain","First Name":"Abhishek"}</json>`, if not, you would need to use `json-to-xml(unparsed-text('file.json'))//*[@key = 'Contact Id']`.

Comment: I'm amazed how amazing XML/XSL could be if browsers pushed beyond XSL 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like JSON data. You tagged your question as XSLT 2.0, but if your processor is capable with [xslt-3.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-3.0), you can use `parse-json()` to get a map, or `json-to-xml()` to apply templates to it.

Other than that, it gets a bit ugly by using regexes, i.e. something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '.*Contact Id.:.(\d+).*', '$1')" />
```